# Is there any method in doctrine to connect mongodb or sql using connect through ssh tunnel

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

Is there any method in doctrine to connect mongodb and SQL using connect through ssh tunnel?

Currently I am using this way.
This is my config file. But know I have to connect remotely using ssh tunnel.

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: "mongodb://localhost:27017"
        options: {}
default_database: "dbname"
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot establish a ssh tunnel with PHP or symfony.
This is a infrastructure problem. Symfony is only the application and should not care about its environment.

It's recommended to build your application **envirnment agnostic** and add some configuration options with **environment variables**.

Here is a link how to achiev this in Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

The best practice omn how to build environment agnostic apps is called **Twelve-Factor-App**. You can find more details about that topic here: https://12factor.net/de/